# Native Audio Player in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio, cocos2d-iphone

Currently I am working on a cocos2d project.In my project,i have to add an audio for the corresponding word.for eg,If there is a word called APPLE,then i have to add APPLE audio.Instead of this,is there any other way that iphone framework automatically trace the word and play it...

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Characters are less than 100 than you can use

> googles translate.google.com translate_tts service sample link is located below. You need to use UIWebView to load particular request like
>
> NSString *yourRequestURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=%@&q=%@", languageTOConvert, YourWord];
>
> [yourUIWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:yourRequestURL]]];

Sample link is
http://sites.google.com/site/readtextextension/home/applications-on-the-web

You need to give credit too to Google like Powered by Google or something like that.